# PHP store a single variable on the server?

Tags: php

I want to store a single integer like so:

```
<?php

$_SERVER['amount'] = 54;
echo($_SERVER['amount']);

?>
```

And be able to modify it, as well as be accessed from every new php session. However whenever the session ends the server variable disappears. How can i store a single variable on the server without a database? A .txt file seems kinda unnecessary for 2 characters stored.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to use `$_SESSION`? Also you don't need brackets to echo variables. You have two storage options really, cookies/sessions or a SQL database. The latter is over kill for as you said just 2 characters.

Comment: Doesn't the session end when the browser gets closed?

Comment: I want the variable to be static just like a text file in FTP.

Comment: Not if you put this before your use of sessions `session_start();` you can set the lifespan of them.

Comment: Okay but i don't want the variable to be unique to each session. User A and user B should both see the same variable. Will setting it as a session variable allow that? maybe there's something I'm not understanding about sessions

Comment: If your script sets it to 54 it will be 54 for everyone.

Comment: In the header of your website, (assuming you have one) why not just set it as a variable that gets read every time a page loads?

Comment: @mikehomme ahh smart, in between xml tags or something like that. :)

Comment: @Dave as soon as i deleted the session variable (after setting it) it no longer showed 54

Comment: Storing in header seems like the way to go.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 - Ya, I think that would be easiest, and if you wanna get fancy, assuming the value will never change, define it as a constant instead of a plain old variable.

Comment: @ThatGuy343 thats because you didn't learn how to use sessions properly :) But no matter you have used a different solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your storage options are a file, a hardcoded variable in the PHP code, a database table, a cookie or a session variable, as I understand it. Probably the most elegant solution if you already are using a database is to add a new table with your permanent data variables.

Another solution, if you are looking for a quick and dirty solution, is to add a global php variable with a magic number, which is really what you are trying to do with your server variable, eg `global $_AMOUNT = 54; // The amount is always 54 for all users.` That doesn't really meet your requirement of being able to modify it each time the page is accessed, though.

$_SERVER is a superglobal, which is read from a file each time PHP is initiated on every pageload. You are not writing to the file that the variable is read from, and so it resets each time the script executes.

Just make a database table, in my opinion. Make one row for the table, amount. I am willing to bet the table will grow over time as you add more global variables.

Answer (score 4):

You could use file_put_contents and create a kind of cache file then use file_get_contents to retrieve the data..

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) AND 
[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

something like

```
$data = array(
    'something' => 'this',
    'somethingelse' => 'again',
);

$settings = json_encode($data);

file_put_content( 'settings.txt', $settings);

//then
$texstSettings = file_get_contents('settings.txt' );
$settings = json_decode(texstSettings);
```

Comment: unless you want to use jquery local storage or something. but that solution is specific to the user. if you wanna use sqlite or something that maybe more then file_put_contents but thats really the only thing you could probably do.

Comment: IMO this is way overboard for what he's asking to do.